# New pipe operator |> gives 'unexpected token' flag in RStudio, although the code runs correctly

Tags: r, pipe, rstudio, unexpected-token

I want to use the new pipe operator `|>` in Rstudio, but when I use it in any fashion I get the *unexpected token '>'* flag. For example, writing

```
"hi" |> print()
```

gives me

[image]

The code, however, executes alright.
Why am I getting that error flag, why is the code executing regardless of it, and what should I do to address this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an updated RStudio version. Make sure you are running the official release with support for the new features in R 4.1 which is version `1.4.1717` (or later). (I think technically you can go back as far as version `1.3.1093` for preview support for the new features, but those were not official releases.)